# Wierd react useEffect and socketio behaviour

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

When i try to console log the message coming from the socket, the connection gets is established and everything is working properly.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import io from 'socket.io-client'

const App = () => {
    const socketio = io('http://localhost:5000')
    const [time, setTime] = useState("")
    useEffect(() => {
        socketio.on('message', msg => {
            console.log(msg.time)
        })
    }, [])
    return (
        <div className="app">
            {time}
        </div>
    )
 }
```

When i try to do `setTime(msg.time)` instead of `console.log(msg.time)` hundreds of requests are being sent and my browser crashes.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import io from 'socket.io-client'

const App = () => {
    const socketio = io('http://localhost:5000')
    const [time, setTime] = useState("")
    useEffect(() => {
        socketio.on('message', msg => {
            setTime(msg.time)
        })
    }, [])
    return (
        <div className="app">
            {time}
        </div>
    )
 }
```

Why is this happening and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`io` has side effects. You create a connection everytime you call it. Because you call it in the render phase, everytime the state of the component is updated, a new connection will be established.

The easiest way to prevent that would be to memoize it.

```
const socketio = React.useMemo(() => io('http://localhost:5000'), [])
```

or move it to be part of the state of the component, and connect in a `useEffect`.